# Setting the innerHTML of an anchor tag through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, anchor, innerhtml

I have an anchor tag on an ASP.NET page, whose text (inner HTML) I wish to populate, through JavaScript, with an integer retrieved from a Web Service.

I tried this using the following:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        GetEntityCount([{ domId: document.getElementById("entityCountIndicator")}]);
    });
</script>

<a id="entityCountIndicator"></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function GetEntityCount(domId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: webServiceProxy + '/GetEntityCount',
        cache: true,
        success: function (xml) { GotEntityCount($(xml).text(), domId); }
    });
}

function GotEntityCount(entityCount, domElement) {
    if (isNaN(entityCount)) return;
    domElement.innerHTML = entityCount.toString();
}
```

but it did not work.

After examining the variables in FireBug, and doing a bit of experimentation I managed to get it working by changing the line that sets the innerHTML to:

```
domElement[0].domId.innerHTML = entityCount.toString();
```

This seemed to do the trick, but I have no idea why it is working or what is happening here.

Why is the document.getElementById("entityCountIndicator") call apparently returning an array, rather than a single element? And why do I then have to probe the first element of that array and set innerHTML on its domId property?

Comment: It looks like you're passing an array to the GetEntityCount method. I suppose javascript interprets it as such: I'm no javascript expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your are passing an array in

```
[{ domId: document.getElementById("entityCountIndicator")}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't possibly work, as:

- Your passing an array as your first argument (GetEntityCount([{ domId: document.getElementById("entityCountIndicator")}]);), but next try to write the innerHTML from the second element (domElement)
- Why are you passing an object inside an array as your domElement, rather than only the element like this: GetEntityCount(0,document.getElementById("entityCountIndicator"));
- And here you seem to only pass an id, rather than a dom element: GotEntityCount($(xml).text(), domId);

Edit: I guess I took too long to answer, nevermind in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway, David. My mistake was to "borrow" some code from somewhere else without really understanding what it was doing. The original code passed in an array, but my code doesn't need to.